# Custom control Openui5

Tags: sapui5

```
    sap.ui.core.Element.extend("custom.barNlineChartControl", { metadata : {
            properties : {
                "Job" : {type : "string", group : "Misc", defaultValue : null},
                "Threshold" : {type : "int", group : "Misc", defaultValue : null},
            }
        }});

sap.ui.core.Control.extend("control.barNlinechart", { 
        /* the control API */
        metadata : {
            aggregations : {
                "items" : { type: "custom.barNlineChartControl", multiple : true, singularName : "item"}
            },
            events: {
                "select" : {},
                "selectEnd": {}             
            }           
        },

    //D3 Code below:
    onAfterRendering: function() {
            var that = this;
            /* get the Items aggregation of the control and put the data into an array */
            var aItems = this.getItems();

            var data = [];
            for (var i=0;i<aItems.length;i++){
                var oEntry = {};
                for (var j in aItems[i].mProperties) {
                    oEntry[j]=aItems[i].mProperties[j];
                }                   
                data.push(oEntry);
            }
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Code of view & control

```
   multiBarLineGraph = new control.barNlinechart({
    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L12 M12 S12"}),
   items: {
            path : "/genericData", 
            template : new custom.barNlineChartControl({Job:"{Job}",Threshold:"{Threshold}"}),
            }   
    }),

    var multiBarData = {
                    "genericData":[
                                  {
                                          "Job": "Doctor",
                                          "Threshold": 45,
                                          "Hospital1": 30,
                                          "Hospital2": 100,
                                          "Hospital3": 90,
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "Job": "Teacher",
                                          "Threshold": 65,
                                         "School1": 60,
                                          "School2": 75,
                                        },
                                      ]};
```

When the alert in d3 code executes I get Job & Threshold but other data from JSON array are missing which is obvious as the properties set here only accept job and threshold. As the JSON is dynamic how to write custom control so that I can pass the complete data to control everytime no matter how dynamic the data be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use type: "any" for your items and dont use the element custom.barNlineChartControl at all:

Edit: as an aggregation controls the lifetime of the aggregated objects you have to use a property in this case.

```
sap.ui.core.Control.extend("control.barNlinechart", { 
    /* the control API */
    metadata : {
        properties : {
            "items" : { type: "any" }
        },
        events: {
            "select" : {},
            "selectEnd": {}             
        }           
    },
```

and then in your view:

```
multiBarLineGraph = new control.barNlinechart({
  layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L12 M12 S12"}),
  items: { path : "/genericData" }   
}),
```

`this.getItems()` would return an array of whatever has been been set / bound.

Comment: It gives this error `Error: Missing template or factory function for aggregation items of Element control.barNlinechart#__nlinechart0 !`

Comment: Yes, my fault. You have to use a property instead of an aggregation. Updated my answer.